# Welche Bedeutungen kann das Adjektiv "günstig" haben?

Tags: word-choice, adjective

Welche Bedeutungen kann das Adjektiv *günstig* haben?
Wie steht *günstig* zu *billig*?

Comment: [Woxikon](http://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/günstig.php) ordnet das Wort *günstig* 23 verschiedenen Synonymgruppen zu. [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/günstig) hingegen listet vier Bedeutungen auf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Billig* kann (zumindest ein meinem Sprachverständnis) einen etwas abwertenden Geschmack haben.

> Das Teil ist echt total billig. (Im Sinne von "schlecht verarbeitet", "nichts wert")

Im Grunde sagt *billig* natürlich primär etwas über eine finanzielle Eigenschaft eines Gegenstands aus, doch gerade in der Umgangssprache schwingt oft der Hauch des *minderwertigen* mit.

*Günstig* hingegen spricht für mich tatsächlich von einer finanziellen Eigenschaft

> Der Teppich war wirklich günstig. (Er hat wenig gekostet)

Weiterhin wird günstig in der Umgangssprache oft im Sinne von "glücklicherweise" oder eines "glücklichen Zufalles" benutzt:

> Günstigerweise habe ich das Werkzeug bereits bei mir.

Die Negation, "ungünstig" sprich dann ebenfalls vom genauen Gegenteil, also einem "unglücklichen Zufall" bzw. einer "schlechten Fügung".

> Die Expansion von ACME kam wirklich ungünstig für uns.

Comment: Kann ich diese Antwot billigen? Der Verweis auf den - m.E. verselbständigten, ironischen - Gebrauch von "billig" ist nur recht und billig. :) Die Entwicklung kann *günstig* aber auch blühen, wenn es oft genug mit ironischem Unterton verwendet wird.

Answer (score 7):

Es ist herrlich, wie Worte sich verändern:

- "Billig" bedeutet [ursprünglich
  ‘angemessen, passend, gerecht’](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=billig), heutzutage eher "kostet wenig", rutscht aber
  langsam ins abwertende ("Billig-Ramsch" etc.).
- "Teuer" bedeutet ursprünglich [‘wertvoll, kostbar, lieb, angesehen, hochgeschätzt’](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=teuer), ist aber heutzutage ebenfalls abwertend (zu teuer).
- "Preiswert" rutscht teilweise in die Bedeutung, die „billig“ bis vor kurzem hatte ("kostet wenig"), was ich sehr interessant finde, da es eine verwandte Etymologie hat und anscheinend auch die gleiche Wanderung durchläuft.
- "Günstig" (ursprünglich [‘wohlgesinnt, wohlwollend, vorteilhaft, passend’](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=g%C3%BCnstig)) ist heutzutage ebenfalls [ein Synonym für billig](http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/g%C3%BCnstig), jedoch ohne die abwertende Konnotation

Comment: Wundervolle Antwort! Alle wichtigen Wörter, ihre Bedeutungen und deren Entwicklung, und dazu noch die Unterschiede in der Konnotation. Ich möchte noch kurz hinzufügen, dass *billig* auch heute noch (eher selten) in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung verwendet wird: *Recht und billig*, *unbill*, *billigend in Kauf nehmen* (überhaupt *Billigung*, was nichts mit einer Preissenkung zu tun hat). In der Rechtssprache findet man es auch noch.

Comment: @fzwo ich weiß, danke, aber ich habe mich auf die Verwandtschaft mit günstig beschränkt so weit ich es konnte

Comment: Ja, ist ja auch richtig. Darum schreibe ich es auch in einen Kommentar, und nicht in eine eigene Antwort.

Comment: Je nach Betonung kann man dem 'günstig' die gleiche Abwertung mitgeben, wie einem 'billig', und ebenso kann man das 'billig' so betonen, dass es nichts Abwertendes hat.

Comment: @user_unknown über Betonung kann man *alles* abwertend machen ...

Answer (score 5):

Günstig kann neben *preiswert* und *billig* tatsächlich auch *vorteilhaft* in einem weiteren Sinne bedeuten:

> Der Wind stand günstig und so konnten wir den See in kurzer Zeit überqueren.

*Billig* hat wie von Florian Peschka erwähnt manchmal einen negativen Beigeschmack. Es ist weniger formell als die Syonyme *günstig* und *preiswert*. Trotzdem werben selbst Firmen mit diesem Adjektiv für die preisliche Attraktivität ihrer Produkte.

Comment: Ein billiges Argument! :)

Answer (score 4):

Es sollte erwähnt werden, dass *günstig* sich von *Gunst* ableitet:

> ### Gunst
>
> - [1] die Bevorzugung, das Wohlwollen, die Gewogenheit
> - [2] die Erfüllung eines Wunsches, einer Bitte
> - [3] eine gute Gelegenheit, ein glücklicher Umstand
>
> ([Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gunst))

Gunst wiederum rührt von dem Verb Gönnen:

> ### Gönnen
>
> - [1] etwas Gutes angedeihen lassen, eine Gunst gewähren
> - [2] positive Bestätigung; sich für jemanden freuen, der/die sein Glück verdient hat
>
> ([Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%B6nnen))

Aus *billig* ist mittlerweile das Wort *billigen* abgeleitet, etwa: genehmigen, dulden, tolerieren (aber auch: gutheißen).

> Die israelische und die libanesische Regierung billigten am Wochenende die UN-Resolution und die Waffenruhe.
>
> Es gibt Bücher von Autoren, die wussten und billigten, was los war, und die heute noch immer keinen Johnny Walker trinken wollen (Büchnerpreisträger).
>
> <sub>[source](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/billigen)</sub>

*Günstig* hat also immer eine positive Konnotation, wohingegen *billig* auch negativ benutzt werden kann.

Synonyme für die negativ behaftete Form von billig wären etwa:

- schäbig
- minderwertig
- abgedroschen

Comment: "Gunscht gommt von Gönnen," wie der Sachse sagt, :) "gäm et vom Wollen, hieße et Wunscht". - ja, ja, ein billiger Witz.