# Deutsche Wörter für "cheap"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Du gehst einkaufen und du hast wenig Geld. Ich kenne drei Wörter, die du für *cheap* Waren und/oder Geschäfte du benutzen könnest.

> 1. billig
> 2. preiswert
> 3. günstig

Welchen Unterschied gibt es hier?

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/385/1224 - http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9156/1224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Main meaning**

- `billig sein` or `billig` as an attribute to a noun usually means low price but can also mean low quality. As an adverbial to verbs, it usually has either of the meanings:

> Das Kleid ist billig. → low price or low quality
>
> das billige Kleid → low price or low quality
>
> Ich habe das Kleid billig eingekauft. → low price
>
> Das Kleid sieht billig aus. → low quality (or low style in this case)

- `preiswert` and `günstig` mean low price or can be used as euphemisms for `billig`.

**Connotations**

Even if `billig` means a low price, it often carries the connotation of `low quality`.

`preiswert` and `günstig` carry the connotation of `without loss of quality/value` with respect to `billig`. Such, they can be used to characterize a good value to price ratio, but this is rather done using the word `Preis-Leistungs-Verhältnis`.

Answer (score 2):

**billig** means low price, but usually also low quality

**preiswert** means it is worth its price 
(this may be a low or high value, you usually use it for a higher value)

**günstig** means it's a good price for the quality

Comment: These are old interpretations. Nowadays, `preiswert` and `günstig` usually just chararacterize a low price with a high value to price ratio characterized by `Preis-Leistungs-Verhältnis`.

Comment: i don't think preiswert and günstig are the same - i disagree here. I don't use them that way and neither do most people i know..

Comment: Could you give an example showing the difference between `preiswert` and `günstig`?

Comment: when i buy a tool that is much more expensive than another, but i know it is much better and more durable, the "other" one may be 'günstig', but i would say the more expensive one is 'preiswert' ( = it is 'den Mehrpreis wert')

Comment: OK, do most people of the area you live in use `preiswert` that way or is it most people of the job you work in?

Comment: i can't say at the moment, i would have to ask them at the office. We usually don't talk that much about pricing of stuff at work..

Answer (score 2):

For all my life, the antonym for "teuer" has been "billig". It is also used to indicate shit quality but it did by no means add that notion to everything.

Marketing fears it does though and so they refrain from using it in favor of the less negative sounding "günstig" and "preiswert". I do not agree with the other answer that there is a difference. They all signify "cheap" for the general public.

The constant bombardment with "günstig" and "preiswert" through adds does have an impact on which word people use in their daily life but at least in Berlin "billig" is BY FAR the most natural one. If someone avoids it, it always feels forced to me.

Comment: Der Volksmund weiß: "Billig gekauft ist teuer bezahlt."

Comment: @Ingo: "Volksmund tut Bullshit kund" (altrömisches Sprichwort). Wenn irgendwo 2 Schraubenzieher liegen, ein solider für 8 Euro und ein klumperter für 2 Euro, dann will ich den sehen, der den teuren "preiswert" nennt. Ironisch betonen kann man alle 3 Begriffe.